# Firebird select Different Days from DateTime Column

Tags: datetime, select, firebird

I am writing a Log Viewer,that will be able to show logs between two dates.
Currently, i am using a:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATETIME FROM EVENTSGENERAL A JOIN EVENTSGENERATORS B ON B.GENERATOR_ =    A.GENERATOR_ ;
```

But it returns too many values of each day for example,since the precision of OADATE used,is set to Miliseconds.

How do i select Only One Value per Day?
For example,if there are 100 rows of logs for **day 1/January, Zero rows for days 2/January,3/January and 4/January, but 50 rows for day 5/January** , how do i select : **1/January,5/January ?**

I am using a firebird database,and C# / ASP.NET

Thanks in advance for any replies,and sorry about any bad english mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only want the date part so cast the timestamp to date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(DATETIME as DATE) FROM ...
```